# Listen to phone state throughout the application?

Tags: java, android

I nee to liste to phone state using phone state listener .I have many activities in a project. Should I register the listener to each of the activities or else is ther a better way.

ps: i am not interested to use broadcast receiver

Answer (score 0):

If there are several activities in your app that need to monitor the phone's state with PhoneStateListener, then you can see if it's possible to consolidate these functions into one unit. For example, you may want to use a fragment to handle the phone state and embed this single fragment into multiple activities.

Broadcast receiver may be an option too, although you have your destain towards it. Broadcast receiver is Android's way to handle in-app/cross-app notifications.

The answer really depends on your app's architecture.